# Adding space between columns in a table

Tags: tables, columns

I notice that the space between each column of a table in LaTeX is not quite wide (at least for me). Is there any way to set this? I found the \hspace, but I don't get how to use this in the table.

Comment: @Stefan: exactly the same as yours, sorry for not posting it :) Well I found something bit more general. If we want that this `\tabcolsep` changed everywhere, we can do `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.15cm}`

Comment: @zfm: No, `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{...}` is definitely wrong; the correct way is with `\setlength`.

Comment: @egreg: that's wrong? why? when I try it, I see that the space between column is added

Comment: @zfm: just because it works in one instance, it doesn't mean it will work forever. Trust me and change the value of `\tabcolsep` with `\setlength`.

Comment: @egreg: you meant, change `\renewcommand` with, `\setlength`, right? so in the beginning of the command, I should write `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{...}`, is that ok?

Comment: @zfm: Yes. `\tabcolsep` is not a command like `\section`: it's a parameter which has a value and changing its meaning with `\renewcommand` might break a package trying to set its value with the correct method.

Comment: Duplicate (more comprehensive): [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764)

Answer (score 235, accepted):

The parameter to act on is `\tabcolsep`, whose value is usually 6pt. So

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
```

will double the intercolumn space. The parameter stores *half* the space between columns: in LaTeX each column is preceded and followed by a horizontal space `\tabcolsep` wide.

Comment: In my case `\tabcolsep` is by default `2pt` but this may be the `\documentclass{revtex}`.

Answer (score 220):

You can add space by inserting `@{\hskip whatever}` between the column specifiers, as in

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 1in}c@{\hskip 0.5in}c}
  One&Two& Three\\
  Four& Five& Six
\end{tabular}
```

Actually, you can add whatever you like between the columns in place of the usual intercolumn space, e.g.,

```
\begin{tabular}{l@{ or }c@{\hskip 0.5in}c}
  One&Two& Three\\
  Four& Five& Six
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Really interesting, thanks. For anyone else, if discovered: `\hskip` defines the horizontal space, it is *not* additional to any other measure. E.g. `@{\hskip -0.1cm}` produces a bad output (just test it).

Comment: doesn't play well with ``\rowcolor``...

Comment: Note that this overrides the default space setting, so `{l@{\hskip 0in}c}` means no space between the `l` and the `c` column.

Comment: doesn't play nice with multicolumn for me, not sure what the issue is

Comment: Re: multicolumns: It seems like the multicolumn span includes the space, rather than having the space be outside the column. So it might look right if the multicolumn is left-aligned, but if center- or right-aligned then it won't be correctly aligned with the non-multi-columns. Would be nice to have a solution for this because I'm not sure of another way to control spacing between each column separately.

Answer (score 58):

If you need to adjust the spacing for just one table you could also add/remove some space before the table and restore previous value after it:

```
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-1pt}    
\begin{tabular}{cc}    
text & text    
\end{tabular}    
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this seems better-suited as a comment.

Comment: this was pretty helpful for me just now actually, nice one

Comment: If you need to adjust the spacing for just one table you could put your code into curly braces and the change will affect just the table that is inside { \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt} \begin{tabular}{cc}  ..... }

Answer (score 38):

You can adjust the length `\tabcolsep`, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}  
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
text & text
\end{tabular}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3em}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
text & text
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`\tabcolsep` is the space which is inserted before and after a column. Note, this means that the space between two columns is `2\tabcolsep`.

Comment: @stefan How can I specify a particlular tabcolsep for only one column using pgfplotstabletypeset

Comment: @ADP It seems like this could be posted as a new question, since this question is not about one column only and not related to pgfplots.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a more natural and flexible way to adjust space between rows or columns in tables, you may try [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. You can use `colsep` (also `leftsep` and `rightsep`) and `rowsep` (also `abovesep` and `belowsep`) options with `tblr` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
 hlines, vlines,
 rows = {rowsep=8pt},
 columns = {colsep=8pt},
}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  & Delta \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    & Theta \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda & Mu    \\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{
 hlines, vlines,
 row{1} = {abovesep=1pt,belowsep=10pt},
 column{2} = {leftsep=1pt,rightsep=10pt},
}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  & Delta \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    & Theta \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda & Mu    \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]