# dcolumn decimal column format breaks file

Tags: babel, spanish, dcolumn

AI'm having trouble using the dcolumn decimal format, The file looks like this:[image]

But as soon as I add the formatting in the `tabular*` in `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{3.6}} @{}}` it wont compile and points to a missing `}` which is not the case unless I should add and extra one. If I understood correctly the formatting `*{4}{d{3.6}}` should give 4 columns 3 spaces before the decimal period and 6 after the decimal period to give space for the order of magnitude.
Some of my code is based on the first answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63204/trying-to-replicate-a-table-from-academic-paper).

---

**EDIT**: This example had errors unrelated to the behavior of `dcolumn` as pointed by `@Rmano`. Each `circuitikz` environment was lacking a semicolon `;` at the end of the last line. A better MWE was provided by `@David Carlisle` in the comments and his answer below.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[oldvoltagedirection]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{  singlelinecheck=false,
        font=footnotesize,
        labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\title{\textbf{Impedancia}}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Circuitos RC}  

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape,font=\small]
            \draw (0,2)
            to[R=$R_s$, o-] (2,2)
            to[C= $C_s$] (2,0)
            to[short, -o] (0,0)
            \end{circuitikz}    
        \label{fig:a}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape,font=\small]
            \draw (0,2) to[short, o-] (2,2)
            to[short] (4,2)
            to[C= $C_p$] (4,0)
            to[short, -o] (0,0)
            (2,2) to[R= $R_p$] (2,0)
            \end{circuitikz}    
        \label{fig:b}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.7, transform shape,font=\small]
            \draw (0,2) to[R=$R_s$,o-] (2,2)
            to[short] (4,2)
            to[C= $C_p$] (4,0)
            to[short, -o] (0,0)
            (2,2) to[R= $R_p$] (2,0)
            \end{circuitikz}    
        \label{fig:c}%
        \end{subfigure}
\caption{a) Circuito RC serie. b) Circuito RC paralelo. c) Circuito RC paralelo con resistencia en serie. $R_s=R_p=1k\Omega$, $C_s=C_p=1\mu F$}
\label{fig:RC}%
\end{figure}


\section{Cálculos de Impedancia}    
\begin{table}[h]
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{3.6}} @{}}
        \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{l}{\textit{Frecuencia}} \\
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$10 Hz$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$100 Hz$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$1 kHz$} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{$10 kHz$} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Circuito 1}} \\
    $Z_1 (\Omega)$  & 1.59e+04 & 1.88e+03 & 1.01e+03 & 1.00e+03 \\
    $\theta_1$  & -86.40 & -57.86 & -9.04 & -0.91 \\
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Circuito 2}} \\
    $Z_2 (\Omega)$  & 1.00e+03 & 0.85.e+03 & 0.16e+03 & 1.59e+01 \\
    $\theta_2$  & -3.60 & -32.14 & -80.96 & -89.09 \\
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textit{Circuito 3}} \\
    $Z_3 (\Omega)$  & 2.00e+03 & 1.78e+03 & 1.03e+03 & 1.00e+03 \\
    $\theta_3$  & -1.80 & -14.70 & -8.61 & -0.91 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \caption{Impedancia y ángulo de fase versus frecuencia}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can try to remove the `circuitikz` and see if the problem persists....

Comment: Yes, I did it and it just works. But in this example I will have to replace `{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{4}{d{3.6}} @{}}` with `{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lllll @{}}`that seems to compile just fine without decimal alignment.

Comment: the posted code gives the error `! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.`

Comment: I get an identical error if I delete the `table` environment and the loading of `dcolumn`, so the error shown is completely unrelated to `dcolumn` as the message indicates there should be a semicolon after `to[short, -o] (0,0)`

Comment: If you delete the tikz code with the unrelated syntax error then I think thihs is a better example of the error that you are askig about, it jus needs spanish babel not ikz: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l d{3.6} @{}}
    a & 1.59e+04 
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}`

Comment: I edited the MWE by placing a semicolon `;`  (that was my bad) at the end of the line prior to each `\end{circuitikz}` and that got rid of some of the errors, except for the `error| Missing } inserted`. Compilation was still completed although the expected behavior of aligning at the decimal period did not work.

Comment: see the document in my comment above if that is the error you are asking about it is completely unrelated to tikz or circitikz or the tabular `*` please edit your question to have a more reasonable example.

Comment: I flagged my question for edition. I will edit it as soon as I have the shorter MWE that reproduces the problem with more clarity. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler example not showing unrelated errors is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l d{3.6} @{}}
    a & 1.59e+04 
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.10     a & 1
              .59e+04
?
```

the spanish option modifies `.` you can prevent that with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}


\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l d{3.6} @{}}
    a & 1.59e+04 
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

If you need the spanish decimaldot option but just a normal . here, I couldn't see a defined way (the usual babel `\shorhandoff` mechanism to locally disable changes dos not work for this definition)

Comment: Thanks for your help. You are right, also learned that the `[spanish]`{babel}` package uses by default the colon`,` for decimal separation following the spanish language standard stablished by RAE, while `[ensglish]`{babel} follows the english standard which is the period. I marked your answer, and will leave the question as is with an edit pointing to read the comments as it might be helpful for other users of the forum.