# How to design the columns in a table

Tags: tables

I've copied this source code from the section "Professional tables" in this page [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables), but the original source code is only for a table with `3` columns. I want to extend it to `5` columns, but only concatenate `&` does not work.

```
 \begin{tabular}{llr}
\hline

Gastro   & Grade 1 & Grade 2   & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
\hline
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65    & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
          & each        & 0.01     & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50    & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33     & Grade 3   & Grade 4 \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99      & Grade 3   & Grade 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

The last two columns overlap with the other columns. Do anyone have idea how to extend this source code to more columns?

Comment: The set of braces after `\begin{tabular}` sets the number of columns for the table. Since your table has `llr` it has only 3 columns.  Adding more columns won't help unless you add more columns to that: `{llllr}` will give you 5.  This is pretty basic stuff. Try [Q: What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner? ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginners)

Comment: Also, when asking a question you shouldn't post code fragments, but complete minimal compilable documents.  See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Fixed link: [Q: What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

Answer (score 5):

Tables in LaTeX require a specification for the exact number of columns the table has. This is given in the argument to the `\begin{tabular}` environment.

In your table, you have specified `{llr}` which means the table has three columns. If you want five columns you need something like `{llrll}` (since your decimal column is the one you want right-aligned.)

For most tables, the `booktabs` package is really useful. It provides nicer vertical spacing and different width rules for tops and middle parts of the table. I've used it in the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llrll}
\toprule
Gastro   & Grade 1 & Grade 2   & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
\midrule
Gnat      & per gram    & 13.65    & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
          & each        & 0.01     & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
Gnu       & stuffed     & 92.50    & Grade 3   & Grade 4  \\
Emu       & stuffed     & 33.33     & Grade 3   & Grade 4 \\
Armadillo & frozen      & 8.99      & Grade 3   & Grade 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Possible values for the column specification are:

```
l = left aligned column    
r = right aligned column
c = center aligned column
p{<width>} = left aligned column of <width>
```

There are more complex column specifications, but these are the basics. See the following questions for some more details:

- [How to create fixed width table columns with text raggedright/centered/raggedleft?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12703/2693)
- [How to force a table into page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10535/2693)
- [Adding space between columns in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16519/2693)