# Format tabular cell from csv file automatically

Tags: siunitx, csvsimple

I tried to adapt examples from [5.4
Tables with Number Formatting](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple) from `csvsimple` package, but no success.

Each line in my `csv` file has 20 fields, **all of them** has format like `x.xxxxxx`. Here is the first line:

```
0.500000,0.614231,0.567667,0.580000,0.787222,0.510333,0.797333,0.732000,0.851228,0.804333,0.764000,0.730667,0.879667,0.778667,0.858333,0.726333,0.884000,0.772667,0.959545,0.919667
```

I'd like to create a tabular to print the data but **truncated**, I mean, print only 3 decimal places like `x.xxx`.

I know that `\csvloop{}` has the key `tabular={}` to specify the format (like `tabular={lSS[table-format=2.2e1]}` from the example cited above).

1. Since my tabular should have 20 columns, is it possible to **format all automatically**?
2. What should be the format? `S[table-format=1.3]`?

### MWE

The code below produces the error `You can't use a prefix with \hskip.}`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{tab2.csv}
0.500000,0.614231,0.567667,0.580000,0.787222,0.510333,0.797333,0.732000,0.851228,0.804333,0.764000,0.730667,0.879667,0.778667,0.858333,0.726333,0.884000,0.772667,0.959545,0.919667
0.000000,0.500000,0.867308,0.891667,0.763889,0.694872,0.785256,0.729647,0.844298,0.797917,0.709455,0.675641,0.876282,0.741667,0.851442,0.710256,0.880128,0.694872,0.949519,0.912500
\end{filecontents*}
%
\csvloop{
file=tab2.csv,
tabular=*{20}{S[table-format=1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3]},
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would rounded instead of truncated also work? Then you could try something like `*{20}{S[table-format=1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3]}`

Comment: if this does not solve your problem, could you please add a MWE?

Comment: @samcarter, done!

Comment: Maybe you could have look here: https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/pgfplotstable/

There's a explanation for using pgfsplot table for reading the csv file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{BC14.csv}
0.500000,0.614231,0.567667,0.580000,0.787222,0.510333,0.797333,0.732000,0.851228,0.804333,0.764000,0.730667,0.879667,0.778667,0.858333,0.726333,0.884000,0.772667,0.959545,0.919667
0.000000,0.500000,0.867308,0.891667,0.763889,0.694872,0.785256,0.729647,0.844298,0.797917,0.709455,0.675641,0.876282,0.741667,0.851442,0.710256,0.880128,0.694872,0.949519,0.912500
\end{filecontents*}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}

\begin{document}

{
\footnotesize
\csvreader[%
    no head,
  before reading=\sisetup{table-format=1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3},
  tabular={c@{} *{20}{S}},
]{BC14.csv}{}{%
& \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi  & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix & \csvcolx & \csvcolxi & \csvcolxii & \csvcolxiii & \csvcolxiv & \csvcolxv & \csvcolxvi & \csvcolxvii & \csvcolxviii & \csvcolxix & \csvcolxx
} 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Now it works. Unfortunately not too automatically, since we have to type all those col commands with `&` separator. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is it possible to change cells font size?

Comment: @Sigur You can change the font size before the table?

Comment: If I use `\small` in `table` environment, it works. It is just a curiosity how to change font size inside the cells, for example. Or maybe change col space to avoid overfull.

Comment: @Sigur For col space, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16521/36296 But even with 0 colsep and \footnotesize the table will not fit on a portrait page.

Comment: Ow, thanks. It fits in `\footnotesize` and rounded to 2 decimal, since my margin is smaller. Nice!