# Table looks ugly

Tags: tables, revtex

I am trying to create a table, which has four columns, but somewhat what the table has ugly looking.

```
\documentclass[%
 preprint,
 doublecolumn
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
prc,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcr} 
\textrm{$\theta$}& \textrm{$R(\theta)\pm \sigma R(\theta)$ }& \textrm{$Y(\theta) \pm \sigma {Y(\theta)}$} & \textrm{$\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ $\pm \sigma$ $\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ }\\
\colrule
0& 2.970$\pm$
10&2.774$\pm$
20&2.800$\pm$
30&2.526$\pm$
40&2.401$\pm$
50&2.399$\pm$
60&2.066$\pm$
70&2.174$\pm$
80&2.161$\pm$
90&2.091$\pm$
100&2.187$\pm$
110&2.272$\pm$
120&2.181$\pm$


\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If you create this table, you will see the part

```
\textrm{$\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ $\pm \sigma$ $\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ }
```

is in different place. 
Can you help me?

I really appreciate your support.

Comment: I your question you mention 4 columns, but you only specify 3 columns. There must be an error message such as `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.` Therefore add a fourth column specifier (for example `\begin{tabular}{lcrr}` or something else depending on the desired horizontal alignment. You will also have to add `\\ ` in order to start a new row.

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as posted, has two severe problems and quite a few less severe problems.

- There's an `\end{table}` statement but no `\begin{table}` statement.
- The declaration `\begin{tabular}{lcr}` cannot be correct since it sets up only three columns, whereas the table's header alone features for columns. I suggest you employ `\begin{tabular}{lccc}`.
- The line

  ```
  \textrm{$\theta$}& 
  \textrm{$R(\theta)\pm \sigma R(\theta)$ }& 
  \textrm{$Y(\theta) \pm \sigma {Y(\theta)}$} & 
  \textrm{$\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ $\pm \sigma$ $\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ }\\
  ```

  features no fewer than four [4!] utterly unnecessary `\textrm` wrappers. Get rid of them.
- The document class option `doublecolumn` isn't used. In fact, could it be a mistake? Should you maybe be using the option `twocolumn`?
- If you're concerned about the table being ugly, you should consider (a) getting rid of the `preprint` option and (b) not using the `ruledtabular` environment and the `\colrule` macro. Instead, load the `booktabs` package and learn how to use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`. And switch to from a `tabular` to an `array` environment save having to type lots and lots and lots of `$` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass[%preprint,
 twocolumn, 
 %doublecolumn -- does this option exist?!
 amsmath,amssymb,aps,prc]{revtex4-2}

% I've omitted the entire remainder of your preamble 
% since none of its instructions get used in this MWE
% (minimum working example).

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule macros
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} S[table-format=3.0] ccc @{}} 
\toprule
{\theta} & 
R(\theta)\pm \sigma R(\theta) & 
Y(\theta) \pm \sigma Y(\theta) & 
\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}\pm\sigma \frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}\\
\midrule
  0 & 2.970\pm{}\\
 10 & 2.774\pm{}\\
 20 & 2.800\pm{}\\
 30 & 2.526\pm{}\\
 40 & 2.401\pm{}\\
 50 & 2.399\pm{}\\
 60 & 2.066\pm{}\\
 70 & 2.174\pm{}\\
 80 & 2.161\pm{}\\
 90 & 2.091\pm{}\\
100 & 2.187\pm{}\\
110 & 2.272\pm{}\\
120 & 2.181\pm{}\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To big to be placed in a comment :-)

I'm guessing that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(most of numbers in the table are dummy)

Your code has many issues and serious errors (see [Mico answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519541/table-looks-ugly/519546#519546)). To make yourself more familiar with writing table, see some introductory text as is for example [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

For above shoved table the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\[
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\begin{array}{rccc}
    \colrule
\theta
    &   R(\theta) \pm \sigma R(\theta)
        &   Y(\theta) \pm \sigma {Y(\theta)}
            &   \mfrac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)} \pm \sigma\mfrac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}   \\
    \colrule
0   & 2.970 \pm 123 & 2.970 \pm 123 & 2.970 \pm 123 \\
10  & 2.774 \pm 123 & 2.774 \pm 123 & 2.774 \pm 123 \\
    \colrule
\end{array}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

It can serve as starting point in your effort to rewrite of your table. Since all cells are in math mode, for table I use `array` which is encapsulated in equation environment.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [MWE by Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519552/142180), but with `siunitx` and in text mode (sort of):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\sisetup{
separate-uncertainty,
table-format = 1.3(1),
}
%% don't forget to undo it:
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}

\begin{tabular}{rSSS[table-align-uncertainty = false]}
\midrule
0   & 2.970 \pm 123 & 2.970 \pm 123 & 2.970 \pm 123 \\
10  & 2.774 \pm 123 & 2.774 \pm 123 & 2.774 \pm 123 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

See also [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/adding-space-between-columns-in-a-table) for `\tabcolsep`.

[image: screenshot]