# Table Issue: one column is not displayed

Tags: tables

I created a table, which has four columns and fifteen rows. However, somewhat point, the angle column: 0,10,20,30,40,.... 120 is not displayed.

```
documentclass[%
 preprint,
 doublecolumn
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
prc,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
%\usepackage{hyperref}% add hypertext capabilities
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}% Enable numbering of text and display math
\usepackage{amsmath}
\linenumbers\relax % Commence numbering lines
%\usepackage{latexsym}
%\usepackage[showframe,%Uncomment any one of the following lines to test 
%%scale=0.7, marginratio={1:1, 2:3}, ignoreall,% default settings
%%text={7in,10in},centering,
%%margin=1.5in,
%%total={6.5in,8.75in}, top=1.2in, left=0.9in, includefoot,
%%height=10in,a5paper,hmargin={3cm,0.8in},
%]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{This table contains Cobalt's count rate:$R(\theta)$, count rate without background:$Y(\theta)$, and normalized count rate:$\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ their uncertainties. To obtain $R(\theta)$, divide "C" from Table.~\ref{Co_Count} by measured time, and its corresponding uncertainty:$\sigma R(\theta)$ is $\sigma C$ over time. For $\Y(\theta)$, subtract background count rate from$R(\theta)$. Its corresponding uncertainty is calculated by using Eq.~(\ref{eq:two}). Normalized count rate is divide $Y(\theta)$ by Y(0). Its uncertainty is from Eq.~(\ref{eq:one})}

\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{lcrr} 
\textrm{$\theta$}& \textrm{$R(\theta)\pm \sigma R(\theta)$ }& \textrm{$Y(\theta) \pm \sigma {Y(\theta)}$} & \textrm{$\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ $\pm \sigma$ $\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ }\\
\textrm{($^{\circ}$)}&\textrm{$\frac{Count}{second}$}&\texrm{$\frac{Count}{second}$}& \\
\colrule
0& 2.970$\pm$0.070 &2.967$\pm$0.070&1.000$\pm$0.033
10&2.774$\pm$0.068 & 2.771$\pm$0.068&0.934$\pm$0.032
20&2.800$\pm$0.068 & 2.797$\pm$0.068&0.943$\pm$0.032
30&2.526$\pm$0.065 & 2.523$\pm$0.065&0.850$\pm$0.030
40&2.401$\pm$0.063 & 2.398$\pm$0.063&0.808$\pm$0.029
50&2.399$\pm$0.063 & 2.396$\pm$0.063&0.808$\pm$0.029
60&2.066$\pm$0.059 & 2.063$\pm$0.059&0.695$\pm$0.026
70&2.174$\pm$0.060 & 2.171$\pm$0.060&0.732$\pm$0.027
80&2.161$\pm$0.060 & 2.157$\pm$0.060&0.727$\pm$0.027
90&2.091$\pm$0.059 & 2.088$\pm$0.059&0.704$\pm$0.026
100&2.187$\pm$0.060 & 2.184$\pm$0.060&0.736$\pm$0.027
110&2.272$\pm$0.062 & 2.269$\pm$0.062&0.765$\pm$0.033
120&2.181$\pm$0.060 & 2.177$\pm$0.060&0.734$\pm$0.027
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}
\end{document)
```

Thank you in advance. Can you also explain what lcrr mean?

Comment: You have only two rows and 14 columns.

Comment: You need ``\\`` at the end of the rows.

Comment: If I take your code, correct the errors so that it compiles, and add the ``\\`` at the end of the rows, the angle column is displayed correctly. Also, the ``lcrr`` in argument of ``tabular`` is there to declare four columns to the table, the first being left aligned, the second being right aligned, and the two others being centered.

Comment: The statement `\end{document)` cannot possibly work.

Comment: Why you not consider answers to your previous question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519541/table-looks-ugly)? There you already have provided solutions for your problems.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
\textrm{$\theta$}& \textrm{$R(\theta)\pm \sigma R(\theta)$ }& \textrm{$Y(\theta) \pm \sigma {Y(\theta)}$} & \textrm{$\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ $\pm \sigma$ $\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$ }\\
\textrm{($^{\circ}$)}&\textrm{$\frac{Count}{second}$}&\texrm{$\frac{Count}{second}$}& \\

\midrule
0& 2.970$\pm$0.070 &2.967$\pm$0.070&1.000$\pm$0.033\\
10&2.774$\pm$0.068 & 2.771$\pm$0.068&0.934$\pm$0.032\\
20&2.800$\pm$0.068 & 2.797$\pm$0.068&0.943$\pm$0.032\\
30&2.526$\pm$0.065 & 2.523$\pm$0.065&0.850$\pm$0.030\\
40&2.401$\pm$0.063 & 2.398$\pm$0.063&0.808$\pm$0.029\\
50&2.399$\pm$0.063 & 2.396$\pm$0.063&0.808$\pm$0.029\\
60&2.066$\pm$0.059 & 2.063$\pm$0.059&0.695$\pm$0.026\\
70&2.174$\pm$0.060 & 2.171$\pm$0.060&0.732$\pm$0.027\\
80&2.161$\pm$0.060 & 2.157$\pm$0.060&0.727$\pm$0.027\\
90&2.091$\pm$0.059 & 2.088$\pm$0.059&0.704$\pm$0.026\\
100&2.187$\pm$0.060 & 2.184$\pm$0.060&0.736$\pm$0.027\\
110&2.272$\pm$0.062 & 2.269$\pm$0.062&0.765$\pm$0.033\\
120&2.181$\pm$0.060 & 2.177$\pm$0.060&0.734$\pm$0.027\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please get rid of the pointless and confusing `\textrm` wrappers.

Comment: Zarko beat me to it

Comment: It's still a good idea to clean up one's code (or the OP's code...)

Answer (score 1):

- I would consider answers on my previous question(s), especially if they contents explanation, how to write table, where I made errors and if they solve all or at least part of my (residues) problems ([table looks ugly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519541/table-looks-ugly))
- in such a table I would use all available tools for writing uncertainty according to SI (International System of Units, see for example [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units)) standards, especially if they offer shorter and consistent code for my table. Such a tool is the `siunitx` package with excellent documentation about use SI units

[image]

and MWE (Minimal Working Example), by which is generated above table, is:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{This table contains Cobalt's count rate: $R(\theta)$,
         count rate without background: $Y(\theta)$, and normalized count rate:
         $Y(\theta)/Y(0)$ their uncertainties. To obtain $R(\theta)$,
         divide "C" from Table.~\ref{Co_Count} by measured time,
         and its corresponding uncertainty: $\sigma R(\theta)$ is $\sigma C$ over time.
         For $Y(\theta)$, subtract background count rate from $R(\theta)$.
         Its corresponding uncertainty is calculated by using Eq.~(\ref{eq:two}).
         Normalized count rate is divide $Y(\theta)$ by Y(0).
         Its uncertainty is from Eq.~(\ref{eq:one})
         }
  \label{tab:cobalt}
  \centering
\sisetup{table-format=1.3(2),
         table-figures-uncertainty=6,
         separate-uncertainty} 
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{ S[table-format=3.0] @{\quad} *3{S} }
    \colrule
{$\theta$}    
   &   {$R(\theta) \pm \sigma R(\theta)$}
        &   {$Y(\theta) \pm \sigma Y(\theta)$} 
            &   {$\mfrac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)} \pm \sigma\mfrac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)}$}   \\
{\si{\degree}} 
    &   {$\mfrac{\text{Count}}
                {\text{second}}$}
        &   {$\mfrac{\text{Count}}
                    {\text{second}}$}
            &                                       \\

    \colrule
0   &   2.970(70)   &   2.967(70)   &   1.000(33)   \\
10  &   2.774(68)   &   2.771(68)   &   0.934(32)   \\
20  &   2.800(68)   &   2.797(68)   &   0.943(32)   \\
30  &   2.526(65)   &   2.523(65)   &   0.850(30)   \\
40  &   2.401(63)   &   2.398(63)   &   0.808(29)   \\
50  &   2.399(63)   &   2.396(63)   &   0.808(29)   \\
60  &   2.066(59)   &   2.063(59)   &   0.695(26)   \\
70  &   2.174(60)   &   2.171(60)   &   0.732(27)   \\
80  &   2.161(60)   &   2.157(60)   &   0.727(27)   \\
90  &   2.091(59)   &   2.088(59)   &   0.704(26)   \\
100 &   2.187(60)   &   2.184(60)   &   0.736(27)   \\
110 &   2.272(62)   &   2.269(62)   &   0.765(33)   \\
120 &   2.181(60)   &   2.177(60)   &   0.734(27)   \\
    \colrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note:

- in MWE preamble of the MWE are considered only packages relevant to the table
- your problem is solved by correct terminated table rows. This was already emphasized in answers on your previous question.
- `c`, `l`, `r` are columns type meaning *center*, *left* and *right* align of columns contents. By them the tables are specified. In your case `lcrr` means that your table has four columns from which the first has *left* aligned cells' contents, in the second cells' contents are *centered* and in the last two columns have *right* aligned contents. For more details see [wiki LaTeX Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).

  As you can see, in proposed solutions instead of them are used `S` columns' type. They enable to align numbers in cells at their decimal points as well simple writing of the tolerances/uncertainties of reported measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations and comments:

- You *must* supply `\\` ("double backslash") directives to indicate where line breaks are supposed to occur. Line breaks in the input fill do NOT suffice.
- You asked, "Can you also explain what `lcrr` mean[s]?" I'm assuming you are referring to the statement

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{lcrr}
  ```

  The LaTeX kernel sets up several column types for use in `tabular` and `array` environments. Among them are `l`, `c`, and `r`, which stand for **l**eft-aligned, **c**entered, and **r**ight-aligned, respectively.

  In the case of your table, I can see no good reason for using `r` for any of the columns. I'd use `c` for the data columns.
- Do get rid of deadwood code such as the `\textrm` "wrappers". They do absolutely nothing except add code clutter.
- Since the entire contents of the `tabular` environment are in math mode, I would NOT use a `tabular` environment. Instead, use an `array` environment.
- As it stands, your table will be read carefully only by gluttons of punishment. Do always keep in mind that people are more likely to pay attention to you if they notice that you've made an effort to organize the information you wish to present attractively.

  Applying this criterion to the entire `table` environment, I'd say that it would be a good idea to organize both the legend and the tabular material more attractively. For sure, don't just "dump" the legend on readers' heads, in the form of a long and meandering caption. Instead, make the caption short and snappy, e.g., `\caption{Count rates}`, and organize the legend as if it were ordinary running text: use paragraph breaks, and use complete sentences.

  Instead of showing a solid mass of 13 rows of numbers without structure in the `array` (or `tabular`) environment, do provide for some visual interest by adding a bit of whitespace after every fourth or fifth row. Optionally, use the `S` column type (provided by the `siunitx` package) to align the numbers in the first column on their (implicit) decimal markers.

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, % the option is "twocolumn", NOT "doublecolumn"
    amsmath,amssymb,aps,prc]{revtex4-2}
%% Simplified the preamble to include just the bare minimum needed:
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\justifying' command

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Count rates}

\justifying 
This table contains Cobalt's count rate, $R(\theta)$, the count rate without 
background, $Y(\theta)$, and the normalized count rate, $Y(\theta)/Y(0)$, 
along with their uncertainties. 

To obtain $R(\theta)$, divide ``C'' from Table~\ref{Co_Count} by measured 
time; its corresponding uncertainty, $\sigma R(\theta)$, is $\sigma C$ over 
time. For $Y(\theta)$, subtract background count rate from $R(\theta)$; its 
corresponding uncertainty is calculated by using Eq.~(\ref{eq:two}). The 
normalized count rate is $Y(\theta)$ divided by~$Y(0)$; its uncertainty is 
from Eq.~(\ref{eq:one}).

\medskip % insert a bit of vertical whitespace
\centering
$\begin{array}{@{} S[table-format=3.0] ccc @{}} 
\toprule
{\theta} & 
R(\theta)\pm \sigma R(\theta) & 
Y(\theta) \pm \sigma Y(\theta) & 
\frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)} \pm \sigma \frac{Y(\theta)}{Y(0)} \\[1ex]
{[^{\circ}]} 
& \bigl[\frac{\text{Count}}{\text{second}}\bigr] 
& \bigl[\frac{\text{Count}}{\text{second}}\bigr] 
& \\
\midrule
  0 & 2.970\pm0.070 & 2.967\pm0.070 & 1.000\pm0.033\\
 10 & 2.774\pm0.068 & 2.771\pm0.068 & 0.934\pm0.032\\
 20 & 2.800\pm0.068 & 2.797\pm0.068 & 0.943\pm0.032\\
 30 & 2.526\pm0.065 & 2.523\pm0.065 & 0.850\pm0.030\\
 40 & 2.401\pm0.063 & 2.398\pm0.063 & 0.808\pm0.029\\
 \addlinespace
 50 & 2.399\pm0.063 & 2.396\pm0.063 & 0.808\pm0.029\\
 60 & 2.066\pm0.059 & 2.063\pm0.059 & 0.695\pm0.026\\
 70 & 2.174\pm0.060 & 2.171\pm0.060 & 0.732\pm0.027\\
 80 & 2.161\pm0.060 & 2.157\pm0.060 & 0.727\pm0.027\\
 \addlinespace
 90 & 2.091\pm0.059 & 2.088\pm0.059 & 0.704\pm0.026\\
100 & 2.187\pm0.060 & 2.184\pm0.060 & 0.736\pm0.027\\
110 & 2.272\pm0.062 & 2.269\pm0.062 & 0.765\pm0.033\\
120 & 2.181\pm0.060 & 2.177\pm0.060 & 0.734\pm0.027\\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```