# How to change vertical cell spacing?

Tags: cellspace

How to change vertical cell spacing with tabular in the first row of the next table?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{25pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{25pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.0cm}}\hline
  $c$ & $\dfrac{a}{b}$ \\ \hline
  $1$ & $1$ \\
  $1$ & $1$ \\
  $1$ & $1$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

With thanks,

Charles

Comment: Maybe this has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16522/234654).

Comment: I can't compile the package ```tabularray```.

Comment: Any news? You got two answers, does any of them solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

- solution using `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tblr}{c c}
    \hline
c   &   a/b \\  
    \hline
  1 &   1   \\
  1 &   1   \\
  1 &   1
\end{tblr}
    \]    
\end{document}
```

which produce:

[image]

- What you mean with your comment below question is unclear. It works out of box, however, you need to have installed `tabularray` package. The recent version (2022A)  is available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray), however, Overleaf support a older version which in your case works fine too.
- Anyway, with "classic" tables package as are `makecell` package for additional vertical space in cells, `array` for table and if you liked `nccmath` for medium sized fraction in second column header:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{makecell}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \makegapedcells
\begin{array}{c c}
    \hline
c   &   a/b \\  % or if you prefer c   &   \dfrac{a}{b}
    \hline
  1 &   1   \\
  1 &   1   \\
  1 &   1
\end{array}
    \]
or if you prefer    
    \[
    \makegapedcells
\begin{array}{c c}
    \hline
c   &   \mfrac{a}{b} \\
    \hline
  1 &   1   \\
  1 &   1   \\
  1 &   1
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution if you have `booktabs` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{25pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{25pt}
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} % <-- new

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.0cm}}\hline
  \specialrule{0em}{2pt}{2pt} % <-- new
  $c$ & $\dfrac{a}{b}$ \\
  \specialrule{0em}{2pt}{2pt} % <-- new
  \hline
  $1$ & $1$ \\
  $1$ & $1$ \\
  $1$ & $1$ 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The `specialrule` adds the additional space here (a rule without width itself but has space above and below it) which is defined as (according to the [manual](https://mirrors.hit.edu.cn/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf#page=6))

```
\specialrule{<wd>}{<abovespace>}{<belowspace>}
```

[image: result]