# Latex recreate table with different columns size

Tags: tables, tabularx, overleaf

I cannot recreate this table, I don't know why. I tried with p{3cm} and similar commands in tabular but it is not the same... also, I cannot recreate
the spaces between columns.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please show some code (a "Working Minimal Example"), otherwise people can't guess what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: For the spacing part did you try [Adding space between columns in a table - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/adding-space-between-columns-in-a-table) ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of MWE )Minimal working Example), a small but complete document with your table, it is possible to propose only a skeleton for your table.

Two solution cross my mind:

- use of the `tabularray` package )in form which can be compiled in Overleaf)

```
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \small
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{4}{X[l, font=\linespread{0.84}\selectfont]}},
             colsep = 4pt,
             rowsep = 0pt}
    \hline[0.8pt]
A. Convetional PID controller
    &   B. Advanced Control I
        &   C. Advanced Control II
            &   D. Advanced Control III     \\
    \hline[0.4pt]
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\[1ex]
            
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
    \hline[0.8pt]
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

- use of `tabularx` and booktabs` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont
                    \RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{Y} }
    \toprule
A. Convetional PID controller
    &   B. Advanced Control I
        &   C. Advanced Control II
            &   D. Advanced Control III     \\
    \midrule
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
    \addlinespace            
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
bla bla bla
    &   some long text in two lines
        &   some long text in two lines
            &   some long text in two lines \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Results of both proposition are very similar:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. Since you don't want vertical lines, you can add empty columns, and when you compile that it will create spaces between columns.

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{table}[]
     \centering
     \caption{}
     \label{tab:my-table}
     \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{%
     \begin{tabular}{lllllll}
     \hline
     A &  & B  &  & C  &  & D  \\ \hline
     1 &  & 2  &  & 3  &  & 4  \\
     5 &  & 6  &  & 7  &  & 8  \\
     9 &  & 10 &  & 11 &  & 12 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}%
     }
     \end{table}
     \end{document}
```

[image]